# Yii2 internationalization: What means @@?

Tags: yii2, translation

When writing translations for Yii2 message strings, sometimes there are translations enclosed in a double at-sign: `@@`, e.g.

```
'Awesome, almost there. ' => '@@Fast geschafft. @@',
```

What does this mean? Is the translated string obsolete and no more found in the source code?

I could not find any documentation about that.

Comment: isnt that a german translation on the right against the english on the left?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam: yes, but an old one. The text ```"Awesome, almost there. "``` was changed in the code and so the translation has no anchor anymore. This is why the strings enclosed in ```@@``` can be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found in docs - quite hidden in "internals" chapter ["Translation workflow / Framework messages"](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/da447fd1bb9778b8b76994f3e3e14f9748c67625/docs/internals/translation-workflow.md#framework-messages):

> Messages that no longer need translation will have their translations
>   enclosed between a pair of '@@' marks.

So, translation messages in folder `messages/...` can be deleted safely since there is no usage anymore in the code.